# Storing character that throws error flag in cin using cin.get

Tags: c++

I am trying to store the character that throws the fail bit in a cin statement. Essentially what i am trying to do is have the user enter two numbers to be compared, but if the user enters something like "111x 222c" than it stores the x and c in another variable, error1/2. I can only use conditional operators and if statements, this is my code so far, I dont know what else to do, if anyone can help it would be much obliged. Thank you in advance

edit

full code

```
   int main()
    {
    double num1, num2;
    num1 = num2 = 0;
    char error1, error2;
    error1 = error2 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter two numbers with a space in between each, and then 
    press enter.\n";
    //cin >> num1 >> num2;// number input

    if(!(cin >> num1)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.get(error1);
        //cin.ignore(2, '\n');
        
    }

    if (!(cin >> num2)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.get(error2);
        cin.ignore(1, '\n');
        
    }
    cout << "Error value: \n" << error1 << endl;
    cout << "Error value2: \n" << error2 << endl;
    if (num1 == num2) {//check if numbers are equal
        cout << "The numbers are equal.\n";
    }
    else if (num1 > num2) { cout << "Number one is greater.\n"; }//check if 
    number one is greater
    else { cout << "Number two is greater\n"; }//else number two is greater

    return 0;
    }
```

edit
If i enter "1x 2c", the x is stored in error2 and the 2c is ignored.

Comment: If you want to prase your user input more carefully, simple cin/scanf do not works well! They are built for get the structure input. you can use `getchar` to get `char` one by one and deal with those `char` by hand.

Comment: Could younshare entire code block ?

Comment: I recommend crafting a [mre], and if you don't get part way through making the MRE, realize the problem, and squash the bug, add the MRE to the question. MRE is a great debugging technique and very often if you make the MRE early in the question writing process, there's no need to finish making the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fake code:

```
let error = ['', '', ''];
let num = [0, 0];
let i = 0;
let enum {
    READ_DIGIT,
    GET_ERROR,
} state = GET_ERROR;
match ch = getchar() {
    $is_digit => {
        state = READ_DIGIT;
        num[i] = 10 * num[i] + (ch - '0');
    }
    _ => {
        if (state == READ_DIGIT) {
            assert!(i == 0 || i == 1);
            i ++;
            state = GET_ERROR;
        }
        error[i].push_back(ch);
    }
};
```

As what I say in comment, standard input function/object is just for structural data but not for others.